# XPath: Getting a node by attribute value of subnode

Tags: xpath

People, could you please help me with this XPATH. Lets say I have the following HTML code

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td class="clickable">text</td>
      <td>value1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>value2</td>
      <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to build a XPath that will pick `<tr>`that have `<td>` with value *text* AND attribute class equals *clickable*.
I tried the following xpath:

```
//tr[contains(.,'text')][contains(./td/@class,'clickable')]
//tr[contains(.,'text')][contains(td/@class,'clickable')]
```

but none of those worked

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
//tr[contains(td/@class,'clickable') and contains(td, 'text')]
```

---

Demo using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html):

```
$ xmllint input.xml --xpath "//tr[contains(td/@class,'clickable') and contains(td, 'text')]"
<tr>
  <td class="clickable">text</td>
  <td>value1</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find `tr` with a `td` having value `text`  and a `td` (maybe, another) with attribute class equals clickable, use answer of @alecxe.

If that is one `td` with two condition then

```
//tr[td[.='text' and @class='clickable']]
```